# Database design for news feed

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have one table `news_feed_card` which contains the following columns:

**news_feed_card**

```
id serial
card_type int
published_at date
```

Each `news_feed_card` can only have one news post. The problem is that I have two different news sources (from news sites & from twitter) and each news source has different properties. So I've created two tables `source_article` and `source_twitter`. Each table has a FK to `news_feed_card.id`.

**source_article**

```
id serial
title string
text text
url string
[FK] news_feed_card_id
```

**source_twitter**

```
id serial
user_id int
user_handle string
user_screen_name string
title string
text text
url string
profile_image_url string
retweet_count int
favorite_count int
[FK] news_feed_card_id
```

Is my approach correct? What I'm thinking is what if by accident have two news source linked to one `news_feed_card`. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

There are not something like the rigth design. Each one has his own adventages and disadventages.

Other alternatives are:

1. Put all columns in the same table (is more fexible if new sources apears, it is simplier, and you only has to add columns if the new source has more attributes)
2. Put the main columns (i.e. title, source_id, text, url, date, card_type) in the news_feed table and add two tables one for the other attributes (i.e. table news_feed_attrs_value with columns news_feed_id, attr_id, value) and other for the attribute definitions (i.e. attr_id, attr_type). Is more flexible but more complicated.
3. The same of option 2 adding news_feed_attr_source for having a white list of attributes for each source. Is more complicated and the flexibility is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach you can try.

You can create a `source` table and two subset tables - `source_article` and `source_twitter`.

The relationship between `news_feed_card` and `source` table is one-to-one. The source table has the fields common to both article and twitter as shown below.

```
id serial
title string
text text
url string
news_feed_card_id [FK with unique constraint]
```

This will allow only one `source` record for a `news_feed_card` record.

An alternative is to have the `news_feed_card_`id as the primary key for this `source` table.

The `source_article` and `source_twitter` tables:

**source_article:**

```
id serial
source_id
...other fields specific to source article
```

**source_twitter:**

```
id serial
source_id
...other fields specific to source twitter
```

Optionally, you can include source table field(s) like `title` within the `source_article` and `source_twitter` tables depending upon your querying needs.